# VHDL code for pulse signal with variable working cycle

Tags: controls, logic, vhdl

I need to create a VHDL code for this situation:

**Draw a control circuit that generates a pulse signal with:

- fixed working frequency (100 KHz)
- variable working cycle
  The phase difference should be increased or decreased by the direction of the spin of a rotary control of 8 bits.**

Additional info:
D = t (on) / T

- D = working cycle
- t (on) = Time the activated signal lasts (rotary control of 8 bits)
- T = signal period (constant)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be wanting to generate a mark:space ratio of between 1:255 and 255:1, so you will need a clock frequency of 256 * 100kHz.

An 8 bit incrementing counter can be left free-running clocked at that rate.

Now have a flop that is SET when the counter overflows from X'FF to X'00 and that CLEARS when the timer value makes the transition from N-1 to N. Where N is the 8 bit value on your duty cycle setting control and controls the width of the mark.

The threshold controlled flop's output is your variable duty cycle 100kHz.